# DebianEDU repaire broken ldap database & dhcp server

Tags: debian, database, ldap, dhcp

We a have  **DebianEDU 5.0.9 codename lenny**

Last week it crashed, DHCP I get error:

> Cannot find host LDAP entry dhcp (&(objectClass=dhcpServer)(cn=dhcp))
>
> LDAP: no space left on device, cannot be recovered, err 28 .**

First I noticed was that the `DHCP` server stop functioning and when I tried to restart it I got this error:

> tjener:~# invoke-rc.d dhcp3-server start
>    dhcpd self-test failed. Please fix the config file.

The error was:

> Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server V3.1.1

Copyright 2004-2008 Internet Systems Consortium.
 All rights reserved.
 For info, please visit http://www.isc.org/sw/dhcp/

> Connecting to LDAP server ldap:389
>
> Successfully logged into LDAP server ldap
>
> Cannot find host LDAP entry dhcp (&(objectClass=dhcpServer)(cn=dhcp))
>
> Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
>
> invoke-rc.d: initscript dhcp3-server, action "start" failed.

I **tried** following how to repair the error from:

http://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu/Documentation/Lenny/Upgrades#DHCP_service_needs_to_repaired

- First the file `"/usr/share/doc/dhcp3-server-ldap/dhcpd-conf-to-ldap.pl.gz"` didn't exist.
- So I tried to restart the `slapd`. 
  didnt give any error but i couldnt reach the lwat website (www/lwat or serverip/lwat)
- So I tried to repare `slapd`:

  ```
  stop slapd.  invoke-rc.d slapd stop
  check syslog or ps output that it have truly stopped.
  run  sudo -u openldap slapindex
  ```

This resulted in:

> bdb_db_open: database "dc=skole,dc=skolelinux,dc=no" : unclean shutdown detected;
>   attempting recovery.
>
> bdb(dc=skole,dc=skolelinux,dc=no): unable to join enviroments
>
> bdb(dc=skole,dc=skolelinux,dc=no): write 0x16ca29d0, 8192: No space left on device
>
> bdb_db_open: database "dc=skole,dc=skolelinux,dc=no" cannot be recovered, err 28. Restore from Backup!
>
> bdb_db_close: database "dc=skole,dc=skolelinux,dc=no": txn_checkpoint failed: Invalied argument (22).
>
> backend_startup_one: bi_db_open failed(28)
>
> slap_startup failed

- I have tried on an virtual server simulating the same error and trying to repair but never managed to recover
  tried: `dkpg-reconfigure slapd` --> which resulted in I lost all access to the database.

(reconfigure webinterface) tried `dkpg-reconfigure lwat`--> which didn't find the database.

tried  `db4.2_recover -h /var/lib/ldap and restart` = no diffrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LDAP: no space left on device, cannot be recovered, err 28 .
```

Does your drive actually have free space?  If so, is it actually mounted as rw (check the output from the 'mount' command.  If it shows up as 'ro', you may have a bad disk)?

Comment: Ah, Noticed the /var was full to the brim with error logs.
Deleted them. ran **slapindex again** ; got the lwat working and could search in the database. But it still couldnt login on clients.
The clients couldnt load the kdm.
After many hours of troubleshooting i noticed that
during my attempts to repaire the ldap i
commented out
 
**/etc/ldap/schema/dnsdomain2.schema in /etc/ldap/slapd.conf.**

wish caused that the kdm not to work on the clients.
uncommented the line restarted the Slapd = could login again.